# pgfplot tikz single plot with 2 y axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have 5 columns of data in a txt. file as 
nxI Bfield1 magmoment1 Bfield2 magmoment2. I am attempting to implement nXI - x axis, Bfield1 and Bfield 2 as my y axis and magmoment1 and magmoment 2 as second y axis on RHS. What I need to do is scale the 2nd y axis w.r.t magmoment 1. I don't want the plot for magmoment to show just scale RHS y axis for their respective magnetic moments. Thanks.
I changed the .txt file name the code below is unchanged.
[ellipbmoment](http://we.tl/t4xL1XxBCe)

[image]

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
    \begin{document}
    \providecommand{\plotdataDir}{plotdata}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogxaxis}[
    xlabel={$n \times I$},
    ylabel={$B_z \left(T\right)$},xmin=1,ymin=0,xmax=100000,
    xtick pos=left,
    ytick pos=left,grid=major,legend entries={$Supermendur                \:2V$,$Metallic\:Glass$},legend pos=north west]

    \addplot[blue,ultra thick] table[x=nxI,y=Bfield1] {\plotdataDir/moment.txt}  node[fill=white, fill opacity=0.5, text opacity=1,anchor=south east,font=\tiny]{$\mu_r=80,000$};

    \addplot[red,ultra thick] table[x=nxI,y=Bfield2] {\plotdataDir/moment.txt} node[fill=white, fill opacity=0.5, text opacity=1,anchor=south east,font=\tiny]{$\mu_r=1,250,000$};

     \end{semilogxaxis}
     %%

     \begin{axis}[
     axis y line*=right,
     ylabel={$M$},xmin=0,
     axis x line=none,
     ]


     \addplot[green,ultra thick] table[x=nxI,y=magmoment1] {\plotdataDir/moment.txt};
     \end{axis}

     \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps I can plot magmoment1 as i did above then somehow hide the plot. This way it adjust the RHS y axis.

Comment: Ok I've solved it by brute force by scaling both axis and hiding the last plot

Comment: FYI, it would be great to add content of the `moment.txt` file to your post as well, otherwise solvers can't reproduce your document.

Comment: Could you please make your comment an answer to this post if you already found a solution which fits you. This is a way how to notify others, even brute force is a solution. It would be also great if you could change the display name from userxxxxx to something more descriptive. We are all humans, right? `:-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the same .txt file name above to ellipbmoment.txt. I've solved it by brute force by scaling both axis and hiding the last plot. Solution below. I have also added the .txt file. [ellipbmoment.txt](http://we.tl/t4xL1XxBCe)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}


\providecommand{\plotdataDir}{plotdata}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{set layers}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[scale only axis,
xlabel={$turns \times I \left(n \cdot A\right)$},
ylabel={$B_z \left(T\right)$},xmin=1,ymin=0,xmax=100000,
xtick pos=left,
ytick pos=left,xmajorgrids,legend entries={$Supermendur \:2V$,$Metallic\:Glass$},legend         pos=north west]

\addplot[blue,ultra thick] table[x=nxI,y=Bfield1] {\plotdataDir/ellipbmoment.txt}     node[fill=white, fill opacity=0.7, text opacity=1,anchor=south east,font=\tiny]    {$\mu_r=80,000$};

\addplot[red,ultra thick] table[x=nxI,y=Bfield2] {\plotdataDir/ellipbmoment.txt}     node[fill=white, fill opacity=0.7, text opacity=1,anchor=south east,font=\tiny]    {$\mu_r=1,250,000$};

\end{semilogxaxis}
%%

\begin{axis}[scale only axis,axis y line*=right,
ytick={500,1000,1500,2000,2500,3000,3500,4000},ylabel={$Magnetic\:Moment\left(A \cdot     m^2\right)$},axis x line=none,ymin=0]
\addplot[draw=none] table[x=nxI,y=magmoment1] {\plotdataDir/ellipbmoment.txt};
\end{axis}
%

%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```